# handling many input files and separating many output files by awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have many input files e.g. 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt
All the file names are listed in filelist.dat in one column.

```
awk '{print $1}' $(cat filelist.dat) > all.dat
```

In file all.dat, the first field values of three files are written.

I want to separate the one output file to three files corresponding to input files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this line a try, I didn't test:

```
 awk '{fn=FILENAME"_out";print $1>>fn;close(fn);}' <yourFileList>
```

this will output for each input file  an output file: "input_out"

**Notes**

- If your file list is not that big, you can use `>`redirection and remove the `close(fn)`.
- the oneliner with `close()` is a quick solution. we could make it nicer, to close the file only by switching inputs, to avoid to open/close file so often. but if it solved your problem, you can use it.